# Use a different task name for Ansible roles execution?

Tags: ansible

I have the current `node` role:

```bash
$ tree roles/node
roles/node
├── defaults
│   └── main.yaml
└── tasks
    ├── main.yaml
    ├── reset.yaml
    └── unmount.yaml
```

Current `provisioning.yaml` playbook is using the `main` tasks:

```yaml
- name: Node Provisioning
  hosts: node
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: node
```

I would like to create a separate `reset.yaml` playbook which uses the `reset` tasks:

```yaml
- name: Node Reset
  hosts: node
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: node
```

I understand I could create a separate role or use tags, but my goal is to use the same role name and define into playbook the `reset` tasks name, instead of `main`.

Is there a proper solution allowing me to use a specific `tasks_from` in my playbook scenario? The example above is a simplified playbook, for proof of concept.

Comment: I would prefer to use variables to call reset task when I want and don't start to duplicate playbooks :) for example: echo "node_reset_needed: True >> host_vars/host1.example.local/all.yml" then using when statement to run the task

Comment: Can you please provide an actual example? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't update questions with solution. Upvote/accept existing answers and/or provide a self answer if you feel it is relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [three ways](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles) to include a role in your playbook:

- Use the classic `roles:` directive in the play;
- Using the dynamic `include_role` task
- Using the static `import_role` task

While the `roles:` directive doesn't support a `tasks_from` argument, the other two options do. You could write:

```yaml
- name: Node Reset
  hosts: node
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: node
        tasks_from: reset.yaml
```

---

Here's a complete test walk-through. If used the following layout:

```
.
├── playbook.yaml
└── roles
    └── node
        └── tasks
            ├── main.yaml
            ├── reset.yaml
            └── umount.yaml
```

Where `roles/node/tasks/reset.yaml` contains:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "This is reset.yaml"

- name: Umount filesystem
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
    file: umount.yaml
  with_items:
    - /run/netns
    - /var/lib/kubelet
  loop_control:
    loop_var: mounted_fs
```

And `roles/node/tasks/unmount.yaml` contains:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "This is umount.yaml; fs: {{ mounted_fs }}"
```

If I run this `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: node
        tasks_from: reset
```

I get as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [node : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is reset.yaml"
}

TASK [node : Umount filesystem] ************************************************
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/roles/node/tasks/umount.yaml for localhost => (item=/run/netns)
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/roles/node/tasks/umount.yaml for localhost => (item=/var/lib/kubelet)

TASK [node : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is umount.yaml; fs: /run/netns"
}

TASK [node : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is umount.yaml; fs: /var/lib/kubelet"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can find my complete test setup [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-75291753-role-task-files).